# scala read config to Map of Map of case class

Tags: scala, dictionary, config, scala-collections

I need to read from a config file and map the config to a case class .It works fine if i have one table as  below

**CONFIG**

```
mapping {
   target {
     oracle  = {
         type = "oracle"
         schema    = "orcl"
         tableName = "my_table"
         query = "select key from my_table where dob='2020-01-01'
     }
}
```

**SCALA CODE SNIPPET**

```
 val targetConfig:Map[String,QueryEngine] = config.getObject("mapping.target")
    .entrySet()
    .asScala
    .foldLeft(Map.empty[String , QueryEngine]) { case ( acc , entry ) =>
      val target = entry.getKey
      val targetConfig = entry.getValue match {
        case validElement if validElement.valueType() == ConfigValueType.OBJECT  => validElement.asInstanceOf[ConfigObject].toConfig
        case invalidElement => sys.error("illegal syntax at $invalidElement")
      }

      targetConfig.getString("type")    match {

        case "oracle" => acc + (target ->  new OracleQueryEngine(vars,target,targetConfig.getString("schema"),targetConfig.getString("tableName"),targetConfig.getString("query"),targetConfig.getString("param")))

        case  x   => sys.error(s"unknow target not defined $targetConfig with $targetConfig")
      }
    }
```

NOW i updated CONFIG with  MULTIPLE tables  in the target mapping.

```
mapping {
   target {
     oracle  =   
        emp = {
         type = "oracle"
         schema    = "orcl"
         tableName = "emp"
         query = "select key from emp where dob='2020-01-01'
        }
        dept = {
         type = "oracle"
         schema    = "orcl"
         tableName = "dept"
         query = "select key from dept where dob='2020-01-01'
        }
    }
}
```

**CODE SNIPPET for the multiple table scenario** *This is giving error  Expression of mutable.Set[Map[String,QueryEngine]] doesnt confirm to Map[Query,String]*

```
 val targetConfig:Map[String,QueryEngine] = config.getObject("mapping.target")
    .entrySet()
    .asScala
    .foldLeft(Map.empty[String , QueryEngine]) { case ( acc , entry ) =>
      val target = entry.getKey
      val targetConfig = entry.getValue match {
        case validElement if validElement.valueType() == ConfigValueType.OBJECT  => validElement.asInstanceOf[ConfigObject].toConfig
        case invalidElement => sys.error("illegal syntax at $invalidElement")
      }
      targetConfig.getObject(s"mapping.target.$target").keySet().asScala.map { key =>
        target  match {
          case "oracle" => acc + (target ->  new OracleQueryEngine(vars,target,targetConfig.getString("schema"),targetConfig.getString("tableName"),targetConfig.getString("query"),targetConfig.getString("param")))

          case  x   => sys.error(s"unknow target not defined $targetConfig with $targetConfig")
        }
      }

  }
```

**PURE CONFIG  CODE**

```
import pureconfig._
import pureconfig.generic.ProductHint
import pureconfig.generic.auto._
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import pureconfig._
import pureconfig.generic.auto._

object PureconfigExample {

  case class QueryEngine(`type`: String, schema: String, tableName: String, query: String)
  type  DatabaseConfig = Map[String, Map[String, QueryEngine]]
  case class TargetConfig(target: DatabaseConfig)
  case class ApplicationConfig(mapping: TargetConfig)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val configString =
      """
        |mapping {
        |   target {
        |     oracle {
        |        emp {
        |         type = "oracle"
        |         schema    = "orcl"
        |         tableName = "emp"
        |         query = "select key from emp where dob='2020-01-01'"
        |        }
        |        dept  {
        |         type = "oracle"
        |         schema    = "orcl"
        |         tableName = "dept"
        |         query = "select key from dept where dob='2020-01-01'"
        |        }
        |      }
        |    }
        |}
        |""".stripMargin

    import pureconfig.generic.auto._

    // See for more details - https://pureconfig.github.io/docs/overriding-behavior-for-case-classes.html
    implicit def hint[T]: ProductHint[T] = ProductHint[T](ConfigFieldMapping(CamelCase, CamelCase))

    val config = ConfigSource.string(configString).load[ApplicationConfig]
    println(config)
  }
}
```

**POM.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>test2</groupId>
    <artifactId>test2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.pureconfig</groupId>
        <artifactId>pureconfig-generic-base_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>0.12.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.pureconfig</groupId>
        <artifactId>pureconfig-generic_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>0.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

</project>
```

**COMPILER ERROR**

```
PureConfigExample.scala
Error:(43, 56) Cannot find an implicit instance of pureconfig.ConfigReader[PureconfigExample.ApplicationConfig].
If you are trying to read or write a case class or sealed trait consider using PureConfig's auto derivation by adding `import pureconfig.generic.auto._`
    val config = ConfigSource.string(configString).load[ApplicationConfig]
Error:(43, 56) not enough arguments for method load: (implicit reader: pureconfig.Derivation[pureconfig.ConfigReader[PureconfigExample.ApplicationConfig]])pureconfig.ConfigReader.Result[PureconfigExample.ApplicationConfig].
Unspecified value parameter reader.
    val config = ConfigSource.string(configString).load[ApplicationConfig]
```

Answer (score 1):

Excuse me, for probably, not the answer you probably expected, but I strongly encourage avoid manual config parsing, because there are tools that doing it for you automatically, without boiler-plate  code and type-safe at the same time. The most popular and probably the best library in Scala eco-system is [PureConfig](https://pureconfig.github.io/).
So in you case the solution would look like something like this:

```
import pureconfig._
import pureconfig.generic.ProductHint
import pureconfig.generic.auto._

object PureconfigExample {

  case class QueryEngine(`type`: String, schema: String, tableName: String, query: String)
  type  DatabaseConfig = Map[String, Map[String, QueryEngine]]
  case class TargetConfig(target: DatabaseConfig)
  case class ApplicationConfig(mapping: TargetConfig)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val configString =
      """
        |mapping {
        |   target {
        |     oracle {
        |        emp {
        |         type = "oracle"
        |         schema    = "orcl"
        |         tableName = "emp"
        |         query = "select key from emp where dob='2020-01-01'"
        |        }
        |        dept  {
        |         type = "oracle"
        |         schema    = "orcl"
        |         tableName = "dept"
        |         query = "select key from dept where dob='2020-01-01'"
        |        }
        |      }
        |    }
        |}
        |""".stripMargin

    // See for more details - https://pureconfig.github.io/docs/overriding-behavior-for-case-classes.html
    implicit def hint[T]: ProductHint[T] = ProductHint[T](ConfigFieldMapping(CamelCase, CamelCase))

    val config = ConfigSource.string(configString).load[ApplicationConfig]
    println(config)
  }
}
```

which in my case produces next result:

```
Right(ApplicationConfig(TargetConfig(Map(oracle -> Map(emp -> QueryEngine(oracle,orcl,emp,select key from emp where dob='2020-01-01'), dept -> QueryEngine(oracle,orcl,dept,select key from dept where dob='2020-01-01'))))))
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks Ivan for your help i tried the same using pureconfig version 0.12.2  getting below error Error:(44, 56) Cannot find an implicit instance of pureconfig.ConfigReader[PureconfigExample.ApplicationConfig].
If you are trying to read or write a case class or sealed trait consider using PureConfig's auto derivation by adding `import pureconfig.generic.auto._`
    val config = ConfigSource.string(configString).load[ApplicationConfig]
Error:(44, 56) not enough arguments for method load: (implicit reader:

Comment: @AjithKannan Thank you for reply. Have you put mentioned all of imports? Also, please, make sure that your are using both `"com.github.pureconfig" %% "pureconfig"` and `"com.github.pureconfig" %% "pureconfig-generic"` dependency. If nothing helps, please, update question with new `pureconfig` code. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks Ivan . i created separate project and imported the pureconfig and getting the compile error. i  updated the questions with the code and pom.xml and error details.thanks

Comment: @AjithKannan From what I see in your `pom.xml`, I guess the current problem that your a using libraries for different Scala version - `pureconfig-generic_2.13` and `pureconfig-generic-base_2.12` - this should be aligned and used either `pureconfig-generic_2.12` or updated `pureconfig-generic-base_2.13` - depending which Scala version you are using. Also, if you are not limited to use Maven, I'd suggest to `sbt` - because it considered as native solution for Scala projects.

Comment: i made both versions same ie 2.12. now below version error is gone    but the other 2 compile errors still there. Error:scalac: error while loading auto, Scala signature auto has wrong version
     expected: 5.0
     found: 5.2 in auto.class       . updated the same in the original question as well.

Comment: @AjithKannan the lib version should also be aligned - try to use `"0.12.2"` for every pureconfig dependency. In my `build.sbt` it looks like next: ```libraryDependencies ++= {
      Seq(
        "com.github.pureconfig" %% "pureconfig" % "0.12.2",
        "com.github.pureconfig" %% "pureconfig-generic" % "0.12.2",
      )
    }```